# PHP How to avoid Question marks in my URL and use a folder like formatted link

Tags: php, url, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have created the website like WOWcrush `http://phone77.ml` I want the url be like phone77.ml/Naveen in title it should have my name but there come ? at the last of the URl like http://phone77.ml/?Naveen only if use ? it works fine or it shows 404 error please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the .htaccess file in order to point /Naveen to the coresponding get var.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L]
```

or you can be more specific like this

```
RewriteRule ^/Naveen$ index.php?section=Naveen [L]
```

$_GET['section'] will contain Naveen and you can use that in your code to show the correct view

Answer (score 0):

By default everything what goes after the '?' symbol is parameters in url. It can be changed, but for that is necessary to properly configure a web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx).
Also can be necessare to made some changes in code or/and configuration of your application.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the question mark as a 'where'. So what you are saying is; 
http://phone77.ml/ 'WHERE' Naveen. It all depends on how you build your site, but apparently you have a clause looking for Naveen in the URL. Maybe something like; `if(isset($_GET['Naveen'])){...}`.

You could also have separate documents for each you pages, then you would link to to that document instead and the URL would look like http://phone77.ml/Naveen.php f.ex.

You might also be interested in looking up the .htaccess document https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html where you can manipulate the URL from.